# Erlang Cowboy crashes with heart-beat time-out

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, cowboy, erlang-heart

I am running a cowboy erlang server. My server was genereted by following the [getting started instructions](http://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/1.0/guide/getting_started/) on the 99s site, and I am running it with a command line:

```
./_rel/myapp_release/bin/myapp_release console
```

Thing is, after a certain while of no activity, the server crashes, and does not recover. The message I am getting is this:

```
heart: Sat Aug 16 22:33:18 2014: heart-beat time-out, no activity for 1771 seconds
heart: Sat Aug 16 22:33:18 2014: Would reboot. Terminating.
{"Kernel pid terminated",heart,{port_terminated,{heart,loop,[<0.0.0>,#Port<0.25>,[]]}}}
```

I know about the heart tool that can be used to monitor a service and restart it after a while if it's not getting any requests (I guess the logic is that if nothing is happening with the service something is wrong), but I can't figure out where in the cowboy application this configuration exists.

So I would ask:

1. Can anyone explain why is the server crashing?
2. If it is indeed crashing "on purpose", where is the configuration to set up things like the time-out period?
3. Ideally the application would restart itself if it's crashed (using a supervisor?). Does cowboy have a built in supervisor for apps that cowboy is running?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?  Getting the same problem on my macbook